# How to install Debian, only with console NO GRAPHIC INTERFACE! its a minimal install

Tags: wireless, networking, virtualbox, console, debian-installer

HOW DO I INSTALL DEBIAN AND CONNECT TO A NETWORK ? Okey. I have my Debian on VirtualBox. 
The problem is that i need to connect Debian to the network.
How do i connect it ?
i'm trying but .. i don't know which command have to type.

Comment: i tried a couple of things but .. nothing, i dont know where i can start !

Comment: First of all, Debian questions are off topic here. Also, please DON'T SHOUT AT US, it's not nice.

Comment: Okey sorry for that ! ..

Comment: @mchid has already answered my question thank you.. next time i'll respect the rules.. im new in "askubuntu" .

Comment: OK, in that case, please [mark his answer as accepted](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Oh ..! ups Thnks for that ! i forgot it.

Comment: Thnks u two for the Help ! really . thnks

Comment: @terdon I usually don't answer Debian installation questions but this one was for installing Debian in a virtual machine which can very well make it an Ubuntu question . . . if the host machine is Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a virtual machine, you will not be using a "wireless interface". Your host machine uses the  wireless interface and the virtual machine accesses the internet through the virtual machine's virtual ethernet connection and so you should most likely focusing on the device "eth0".

During installation, the network should automatically configure itself as one of the installation steps. Your host computer MUST be connected to the internet to provide access to your virtual machine.

After installation,

use

```
lspci -v
```

to gather information on your network-adapters and modules in use.

You cannot use apt-get without either an internet connection or an installation disk containing the needed packages.

You may have to reinstall and select to install networking capabilities during the installation.

The easiest, would be to install "network-manager" during installation.

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

To start network-manager run

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

Either way, after installation, you will have to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update the package list

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to preform software updates

and

```
sudo apt-get install
```

followed by the package name, to install a package